# pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, scikit-learn

Пытаюсь установить `pip install -U scikit-learn`, но возникает ошибка `pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully`.

**Полная ошибка:**

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.2.1.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]
      Ignoring oldest-supported-numpy: markers 'python_version != "3.10" or platform_system != "Windows" or platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools<60.0
        Using cached setuptools-59.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl (987 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.22.3
        Using cached numpy-1.22.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl (12.2 MB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.3.2
        Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
      
        [21 lines of output]
        + meson setup --prefix=C:\Kirill\Python C:\Temp\pip-install-sd5e1rzl\scipy_0228b155d0a541ae84543e809992efcf C:\Temp\pip-install-sd5e1rzl\scipy_0228b155d0a541ae84543e809992efcf\.mesonpy-_l1zhyl3\build --native-file=C:\Temp\pip-install-sd5e1rzl\scipy_0228b155d0a541ae84543e809992efcf\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
        The Meson build system
        Version: 1.0.1
        Source dir: C:\Temp\pip-install-sd5e1rzl\scipy_0228b155d0a541ae84543e809992efcf
        Build dir: C:\Temp\pip-install-sd5e1rzl\scipy_0228b155d0a541ae84543e809992efcf\.mesonpy-_l1zhyl3\build
        Build type: native build
        Project name: SciPy
        Project version: 1.10.1
        WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe
     
        ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
        The following exception(s) were encountered:
        Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл"
        Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл"
        Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл"
        Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл"
        Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл"
        Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл"
        Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл"
      
        A full log can be found at C:\Temp\pip-install-sd5e1rzl\scipy_0228b155d0a541ae84543e809992efcf\.mesonpy-_l1zhyl3\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
      
      Encountered error while generating package metadata.
      
      See above for output.
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      
      [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0 -> 23.0.1
      [notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Помогите пожалуйста, уже долго ищу решение.

> Python: 3.10

Comment: Ни одного компилятора C не удаётся найти инсталлятору. Надо какой-нибудь поставить. Что-то типа Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. Странно, что в ошибке про него не написано, обычно пишет.

Comment: @CrazyElf установил miniconda но не разобрался как им пользоваться

Comment: Нет, это не связано. Миниконда вроде не ставит компиляторы C++, надо отдельно ставить. До миниконды, наверное.